# Ubuntu 16.0 AMD APU DISPLAY DRIVER

Tags: amd-graphics, ubuntu-drivers

Good evening, everyone so I have this PC with AMD APU, where I just fresh installed Ubuntu latest version. Out of the box everything working fine except the display seems having some issues. So what should i do now need help.

Thanks

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: Icons are big and in setting only 1000x 600 though my perfect dimensions 1360x....

Comment: Thank you @Android Dev it seems after updating the system now it's working thank you.